# Rhino Mocks. How to add expectation that event handler was subscribed

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, events, rhino-mocks

I have an interface like that:

```
interface IView
{
     event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> SomeEvent;
}
```

and a class

```
class Presenter
{
     private IView _view;
     public Presenter(IView view)
     {
         view.SomeEvent += MyEventHandler;
     }

     private MyEventHandler(...)
}
```

I'm trying to test this stuff using RhinoMocks and MockRepository.VerifyAll() throws the following exception

> Rhino.Mocks.Exceptions.ExpectationViolationException:
>   IView.add_SomeEvent(System.EventHandler`1[MyEventArgs]); Expected #1,
>   Actual #0.

So the question:

How to add the expectation that event is subscribed?

Comment: How are you adding the expectation when it fails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry guys, I have found what I was doing wrong:

```
_viewMock.Expect(x => x.SomeEvent+= Arg<EventHandler<MyEventArgs>>.Is.Anything); 

Presenter p = new Presenter(_viewMock);

_mockRepository.ReplayAll();

...

_mockRepository.VerifyAll();
```

I had to ReplayAll before I created new instance of Presenter.

Thanks.

Comment: Also make sure you are writing a valid test case, since here is you're covering just a fact that presenter listen to View's event

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I believe my test cases are correct, I had the only trouble with that expectation.